# how to add a vote to update my database

Tags: php, mysql, database

alright,The problem is I can't get my database to add a vote to it on the votes page or my database after an individual on the previous page clicks submit for there vote to a question. Here's my code within my page to retrieve the information and add it to my database and page:

```
      if ($row) {
            // display the poll
            echo '<h1>' . $row['Title'] . '</h1>';
            echo '<p><b>' . $row['Question'] . '</b></p>';
            echo '<table><tr><th style="text-align:left">Answer</th><th>Votes</th></tr>';
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
                $answer = $row['Answer' . $i];
                $votes = $row['Votes' . $i];
                $avote = 1;
                $command = "UPDATE FROM polls SET $answer WHERE $answer='$answer+$avote'";
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare($command);
                $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['Votes']));
```

Comment: `UPDATE polls` not `UPDATE FROM`. Also you don't set $answer. If you're using `PDO` (which I think you are, not sure), you want to use `?` instead of `$...` if you're passing an array into execute. Btw, `SQL != MySQL` (re: your tags).

Comment: For debugging, I suggest you echo or print the contents of the (oddly named) variable containing the generated SQL text. Take the SQL to a different client and test. Compare your SQL to the syntax examples in the MySQL Reference Manual. We can't tell what $answer contains, or is suppoed to contain. We can identify some issues with the syntax. Eliminate the FROM keyword (unless that's the name of the table you're updating,and then it needs to be enclosed in backticks), The SET clause should be of the form `SET col = expr`. (Maybe $answer contains that. But how can we tell?)

Comment: Mysql and ms sql server are 2 different products. Pls remove the unnecessary product tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query is malformed.

Here's the SQL Update syntax:

> UPDATE table_name
>   SET column1=value1, column2=value2, ...
>   WHERE some_column=some_value;

I can't really tell from your code what $answer is suppose to be, nor did you provide your database structure. First you should fix your SQL statement, though.

Comment: Note that `value1` could be an expression e.g `SET column1 = column1 + 1`, or any other expression that returns a scalar. +10.

Comment: i was wondering does mysql and php well in this case the mysql part within the brackets have access to the ++ modifier? so could I use 
UPDATE polls SET $answer = $votes++;. and another thing is I don't know what to do with my where i realize what my problem is and why my database is not changing the where statement is where i have to set which question I chose. so I'd have to access my Question how which i have for ? here i'll try making a quick table and uploading a site with it cause i don't know how to show you my table any other way unless this has an attachment link thing

Comment: the question though is random it's up to what the user picks so do i make another for loop statement with my column question and say do the following: $question = $row['Question' . $i]; and then WHERE {$row['Question]} = $question; aww wait that wouldn't work there's 4 different answer columns and 4 different vote columns but only one column for question. god I wish my instructor was not in Jordan. I have an exam in 3 days. this is the only thing i don't understand how to do, UPDATE through sessions *sigh*.

Comment: Like i understand what you guys all mean but in the WHERE part of the statement the Question is random like user picks it it's not your choice is the users choice, how do you pull that off not knowing i need sometype of SCANNER variable like how they have in java.

Comment: Alright. Lets get this straight and find a solution, on your code extract, it looks like it's pulling a single row from the database (which is a poll) which contains Answer1, Answer2, Answer3 and Answer4 and also Votes1-4 all contained in `$row` and then you output part of a table... then you start updating the database? Why?

Comment: echo "<tr><td>$answer</td><td style='text-align:center'>$votes</td>";
                }
                echo '</table>';
            } else
                echo '<p>Poll ID ' . $_GET['pollid'] . ' not found.';
        } else {
            echo '<p>No poll selected</p>';
        }
        session_destroy();
        ?>

Comment: that is what follows it i was told ot keep my questions short and edit them so i didn't add those parts but i realized another thing it does not know which question i am picking. on the first page it asks for a store with radio buttonsafter choosing that it asks for your favorite product after you submit that it displays the choices "answers" and beside it there "votes"

Comment: i think my problem is I have not shown which question I've chosen from on the first page so it does not know which choice "answer" and which "vote" to go up on which question so I'm thinking the problem is not the SET it's the WHERE

Comment: oh wait everyone can try it themselves go for it this is how it works but you'll notice the last page the votes don't change or they might change once for you and then when you do it again it stays the same

Comment: http://sharmnar.dev.fast.sheridanc.on.ca/PhpExamples/PHPServer/start1.php

Comment: Okay, and what, for example is in `Answer1`, `Votes1`, and `$_SESSION['Votes']`?

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109964/discussion-between-daniel-and-narinderrsharma).

Answer (score -3):

Your query should be like this

```
$command = "UPDATE FROM polls SET column_name = column_name + 1 WHERE column_name = value";
```

The argument after your where clause will be the identifier of the question i.e the primary key or a unique key equivalent to its value.

Comment: so would this work: 
$command = "UPDATE FROM polls SET $answer = $votes + $avote WHERE $answer = $votes"

Comment: This will result in a syntax error.

Comment: UPDATE polls WHERE $votes = $votes + 1 WHERE $row['Question'] = {$_GET['Question']}; will this tell me which question they picked and update the votes for the answer?